# Sending email with file attachment from form using php

Tags: php, file-upload, email-attachments

I have a job application form that needs to allow a user to send a copy of their CV along with some other basic details. I don't need the file to be saved on the server, just emailed as an attachment.

I've followed a few different tutorials and guides, and have come up with the following function:

```
function mail_file ($email,$from,$subject,$body,$file){
$boundary = md5(rand());
$headers = array(
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    "From:{$from}",
    "Content-Type: Multipart/mixed; boundary = {$boundary}"
);

$message = array(
    "--{$boundary}",
    "Content-Type: text/plain: charset = utf-8",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit",
    "",
    chunk_split($body),
    "--{$boundary}",
    "Content-Type: {$file['type']}: name={$file['name']}",
    "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= {$file['name']}",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
    "",
    chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file['path']))),
    "--{$boundary}--"
);

return mail ($email, $subject, implode("\r\n",$message),implode("\r\n",$headers));
```

}

It sends an email - but it's blank, and has 2 attachments (noname.txt and noname).

Would someone be able to take a look at the above, and point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do **NOT** build your own mime messages. especially with attachments. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer to do it for you. They're far easier to use and more reliable... and completely free to boot.

Comment: Get rid of the spaces between `boundary = {$boundary}` and `charset = utf-8`

Comment: Also, your attachment names should be quoted. Content headers should be: `Content-Type: {$file['type']}; name="{$file['name']}"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment`

Comment: Otherwise, listen to Marc; PHPMailer is a good alternative.

Comment: @RobW - Thanks for the tips, the content headers now just give me code errors, any idea?

Comment: 0 ideas; I can't see your code.

Comment: `$message = array(
  "--{$boundary}",
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8",
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit",
  "",
  chunk_split($body),
  "--{$boundary}",
  "Content-Type: {$file['type']}; name='{$file['name']}'\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment",
  "",
  chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file['path']))),
  "--{$boundary}--"
 );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Marc's advice, using PHPMailer is a lot simpler! I suggest anyone trying to send attachments use phpmailer.